# Simple eclipse search problem

Tags: eclipse, search

I use the eclipse File Search option very much to search all files in my workspace for a certain content. But how do I specify that it should only return hits from a fixed search criteria? As an example I would like to find all occurrences of the string:

```
com.mystuff.data
```

but I  also get all the hits for:

```
com.mystuff.data.ui
```

How do I make a "this-string-only-search" when searching files in my workspace??

Comment: Could you be more specific about why the second string should NOT match your search? What characters are allowed before or after the search string, and which are not.

Comment: Because is not an exact match. When you search in a .java file you can check something like "exact" or "whole word". Could be nice if the same was possible when searching the workspace.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, Eclipse don't provide option to search exact word.
You can use regular expression for it.
You can use `\bSearchKeyword\b` to find exact word.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you use **regular expressions**.

**Here are the steps:**

1. ***Select*** the checkbox ***"Regular expression"*** which is located beside the "Containing text" field.
2. In the ***"Containing text"*** field write: **com.mystuff.data\D\W**

**Note that:**

- ***\D*** means "no digit"
- ***\W*** means "no alphanumeric"
- In case you would like to refine the regular expression, click ***Ctrl-SPACE***, in order to get the regular expression assistance.

Hope this helps.

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

Maybe slightly off-topic but this got me tripped and brought me here - maybe useful for somebody else:

- In the Eclipse standard Find/Replace dialogue the section 'Options' (that includes the option 'Whole Word') may be hidden if the Find/Replace dialogue window was previously resized to a smaller size, without any clue to its presence. Resizing it larger brings back the options section. See: [https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355206](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1uth.png)
  and attached shots.[image: Eclipse Find/Replace dialogue window resized with options hidden][image: Full size Find/Replace Dialogue WITH options]
- Eclipse standard Find/Replace dialogue search for Whole Word regards several characters (including period) besides a space as a word delimiter, so you indeed cannot distinguish between "com.mystuff.data" and "com.mystuff.data.ui"
  E.g. search 'Stack' with option 'Whole Word' checked:
  *will* match:

  - Stack
  - Stack overflow
  - Stack.overflow
  - Stack,overflow
  - Stack[overflow]
  - Stack(overflow)
  - Stack-overflow
  - Stack/overflow

  *will not* match:

  - Stackoverflow
  - Stack2overflow
  - Stack_overflow

Comment: Search is not on a single file

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what happened to me. Thans again.

Comment: So beware the underscore character !

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to add space in the start and end of your search term.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>SHFT</kbd>+ <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then on right upper angle select Working Set, then name and specify your resources.

Create Work Set as above, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> check checkbox All occurency, then select your Work Set. Or maybe you can create work set in <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: That will not give me a string used in eg. a plugin.xml file - i need to search for any occurrence.

Comment: Create Work Set as in post, then CTRL+H check checkbox All occurency, then select your Work Set. Or maybe you can create work set in CTRL+H.

Comment: Read question once more.