# Eclipse : search for only a particular word under Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to search for only a particular word under Eclipse IDE .
For example i need to search for a word "sub" .

But the problem is that , when i did ctr l + H and typed the word "sub" , it producing all matching results such as 
submit ----etc , but i want the exact word "sub" in my Search .

Please let me know if its possible ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple eclipse search problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965551/simple-eclipse-search-problem)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using regular expressions in the File Search Dialogue (Ctrl + H). You can use the `word boundaries` modifier `\b` like so :

[image: Eclipse Regular Expression Search]

`\bsub\b` asks eclipse to search for all matches in which sub is both followed and preceded by a word boundary.  Read more about word boundaries **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)**.

Here is a sample snapshot of the Search Results using the above:

[image: Word Boundaries Search]

If you want to restrict the search to the current project then try selecting 'Enclosing Projects' radio option. This option will be disabled if you don't already have a file from the Project opened. To get past this annoyance, I would recommend creating a Working Set with just the project(s) of interest and then restricting the search on that Working Set.

Comment: You may wish to update your answer because "Whole word" option is available in the search window now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from Find/Replace menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>F</kbd>) and flagging the **Whole word** option :

[image: Find Replace]

Otherwise from the standard Search menu(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>H</kbd>) you can achieve the same result using an appropriate **regular expression**, in your case you just need to append a space after(or/and before) the sub text and you will get only the whole word.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , my search is with respect to the Project , but not file . Could you please let me know the Regular Expression of that ?

Comment: @PreethiJain Just put a space before and after the text that you want to search for ...

Comment: hey i pressed Ctrl + H and entered sub , the result is showing all matching words like "submit " , but i want to restrict my search to contain the exact word "sub" .

Comment: great thinking , but then i will miss search like  request.getparmeter("sub") , so i cant do that .

Comment: @PreethiJain : You could use word boundaries to cover such cases. Take a look at my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Select the word and then press **Ctrl+Alt+letter(G)** it will search the word where it is used.

Comment: This produces a search which would find references like `submit`. This does not correctly answer the question.