# import library from ecplise

Tags: java, eclipse

to avoid to add and import manually for each class , I would like to add import com.soft.dor.file ; to all java classes available in a package package1.

Is there a way from ecplise java ?

thanks

Comment: I don't think there is something like global import available in eclipse. I may be wrong too.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but can get what you want. Check out "Save Actions" at Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions. You can set the editor to auto-import and organize imports for you on save.

Comment: I don't think there is a global import in eclipse too, but in java. :)

Comment: @Justin,do you mean selecting the option "Perform the selected actions on save" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you want to add `import com.soft.dor.file ;` to all java classes in a pacakge called `package1`.

Proceed as follows :

1. First select the package `package1` in Package Explorer.
2. Then, press Ctrl + H and click on the `File Search` tab.
3. There change the settings like so :

   [image]

   1. Select the `Selected resources` radio
   2. Select : `Regular expression` checkbox
   3. In `Containing text` type `package package1;`
   4. In `File name patterns` : `*.java`
   5. Click on `Replace`.
   6. In the 'Replace Text Matches' that appears, in the `With:` field type : `package package1;\r\n\r\nimport com.soft.dor.file ;`
   7. Press OK or Preview

   [image]

Comment: Ashutosh, in which step I enter the name of package to import ?

Comment: I would like to add : import com.soft.dor.file ; to all java files available under package1

Comment: ah, ok, thanks!! may be you want if there is a way within ecipse to replace some strings in all java files available in the package ?

Comment: @lola, you would change the replace string in Step 6. Thus for your import you would use the following : `package package1;\r\n\r\nimport com.soft.dor.file ;`

Comment: I have updated my answer for `package1` and `import com.soft.dor.file;` . However, the snapshots still refer to `com.aj.test` and `import java.util.*;` respectively.

Comment: yes, I saw, it's ok, thanks  but I ask you a question about replacing strings, from ecplise we can search and replace , but I would like to replace some strings example  "toto" with "titi" in all java files available in package1 , do I use the same method ?

Comment: Yup.. you can follow the same method to search and replace. Also, take a look at this question's accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826231/eclipse-search-for-only-a-particular-word-under-eclipse-ide/11826811#11826811

Comment: thnaks you but my question was replacing in a specific package , as when I replace it replaces in all java classes

Comment: Nope, it won't do that. That the reason for steps 1 and step 3.1. First select the package within which you want all java files to be searched (Step 1). Then when searching select `Selected Resources` (Step 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang-package is automatically imported.

So place a class:

```
package java.lang;
public class file extends com.soft.dor.file {}
```

So you are able to use the file everywhere

i.e.:

```
package package1;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        file f = new file();
    }
}
```